# dereferencing two list of objects in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project which includes hibernate mappings,in which i have one functionality to perform and that is copying an object to a new object ,but the problem that i am getting is whenever i do copy it copies the object of an entity class but the list of another class which is present in that entity class,object of that is not getting dereferenced,,so due to that the copied list object is affecting the old list object...and  i am not getting the solution for this.how to dereference those two lists.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow - to maximise the chance of you getting a good answer please read the [How to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Personally I think it would be good if you could produce an example of what you have tried and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to clone your object when you create new list of objects.

Please look on that [library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/) .

This [article](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/) is also very usefull in that matter. There are some different kinds of cloning objects. `Shallow Cloning` and `Deep Cloning`. I think you want to user `Deep` one but to be sure please look on that article.

Comment: i checked the link ,,it's talk about Cloner class,but in which lib it's available bcz in jdk1.6 i am not finding any class named cloner.

Comment: please look at another lib http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.com.robust-it/cloning/1.9.0

Comment: I don't know it is written there, but I am sure it is compatible with java 1.7